# How to generate an access token for Azure CDN List Rules Engine Endpoint?

Tags: azure, azure-cdn, edgecast, verizon

I have subscribed to Premium Verizon Plan of Azure CDN Service. With that I gained access to the [Azure CDN Policy Rules Portal](https://cdn.windowsazure.com/HTTPLarge/RulesEngine#/policies) wherein I am able to manage all of the rules pertaining to the CDN Service I have subscribed to.

As part of the compliance program that I am working with as of the moment, I wanted to list all of the available Policies within my CDN Service using this endpoint:

`https://cdn.windowsazure.com/api/v3/rules-engine/v1.0/policies?page_size=20&platform_id=http-large&policy_type=customer&sort=-created_at&state=locked`

My currently problem is that I am unable to generate the access token needed to call the endpoint successfully. As of the moment here are the methods that I have currently used to generate access token for the endpoint:

1. Generate the Access Token using the Client Credentials from the [Identity Dashboard](https://manage.vdms.io/):

   I have successfully generated the Access Token from this step but I
   am unable to see the necessary scope ("ec.rules") needed to call the
   API Endpoint. [Source
   Document](https://dev.whitecdn.com/cdn/api/index.html#Introduction/Authentication.htm#OAuth)
2. Using the Token from the [Azure CDN Policy Rules Portal](https://cdn.windowsazure.com/HTTPLarge/RulesEngine#/policies): 
   I am unable to find the "Generate New Primary" button stated in the [Source Document](https://dev.whitecdn.com/cdn/api/index.html#Introduction/Authentication.htm#RESTAPIToken)

Answer (score 0):

To configure Token authentication & generate tokens on **Azure CDN Premium from Verizon**, you can follow the steps on this document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-token-auth#setting-up-token-authentication